# Path integral and gauge redundancy for slave particle

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, path-integral

In the slave boson, we have $c^\dagger = b f^\dagger$ where $b$ is boson and $f$ is fermion.  There is also a local constraint $b^\dagger b+f^\dagger f=1$ to retrict the Hilbert space and a $U(1)$ gauge redundancy $b\rightarrow be^{i\phi},f^\dagger \rightarrow e^{-i\phi} f^\dagger $

I am trying to write down the path integral representation in terms of the slave particles using

$Z=Tr[\hat{P} e^{-\beta H[f^\dagger,f,b^\dagger,b]}]$

where $ \hat{P}$ is the projection operator into the subspace with $Q=b^\dagger b+f^\dagger f=1$.

The question is

1. Is this formula always correct? (even for other slave particles like slave spin and slave fermion)
2. How to deal with the U(1) gauge redundancy? It seems to me that we still have this redundant degrees of freedom in the path integral representation. Do we need to do something like fix the gauge to remove this redundancy?
3. In general, I hope to find the action $S[f^\dagger,f,b^\dagger,b]$ such that the partition function can be written as
   $Z=\int D[f,f^\dagger,b,b\dagger] e^{-S[f^\dagger,f,b^\dagger,b]}$. I am wondering if we have some systematical way to write down such action for the slave particles.